# how to print keyup element value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am using the following keyup event handler .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.someClass').on('keyup', function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

When writing the keyup event , and typing "qwe".
actual result : "qwe"
desired result :
"q"
"qw"
"qwe"

i simplified it here , but i also tried with closure , what is the right way?

Comment: *I'm* getting the desired result...http://jsfiddle.net/3xAga/

Comment: Closures make no sense here. Try to input letter by letter with ~200ms pause.

Comment: Maybe you are typing to quickly.

Comment: thats exacly my problem. i am writing the 3 letters really fast...

Comment: So why is this a problem? Why do you need to get `q`, `qw` and `qwe` separately? You can always deduce the previous value(s) from the current value (well, to some degree).

Comment: Felix , thats the issue , if i want to capture the typing interval, and print the values as its changing ...

Comment: the reason is i need to log it , its part of my project.

Comment: So, you want to measure the typing speed? Like characters per second, or what? If you just want to log it, if I typed `f` and the next value is `foo`, then I must have typed `fo` in between (obviously). So you could log both `fo` and `foo` just by knowing what the previous value and the current value is.

Comment: thats true felix , but why is the keyup event cant print the right values ?

Comment: i figured maybe its because the value is by ref and its changing before i print it , so i tried saving it first thing .
that didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tricky (ugly?) solution that works even if you type quickly:

```
var prevVal = '';
$('.someClass').on('keypress', function (e) {
    prevVal += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(prevVal);
}).on('keyup', function() { prevVal = $(this).val() });
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FZHZJ/1/

Note it doesn't print on modifier keyup events (ie. backspace, shift, arrows) - if you want that also then reply and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sulotion i used in the end. 
its pushing the value to array when keypressed, and pop it on keyup. 
( the stack is used with reverse .. )

```
var stackValues = new Array();
$('.someClass').on('keypress', function (e) {
   prevVal = $(this).val();
   prevVal += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   stackValues.push(prevVal);
}).on('keyup', function() { 
   var value = (stackValues.reverse()).pop();
   stackValues.reverse();
   console.log('value:', value);
});
```